# incorrect behavior of upper_bound

Tags: c++, upperbound

```
vector<int> v = {0,1,3,2};
auto x = upper_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 1);
cout<<(*x);
```

This block of code gives output 24576

```
vector<int> v = {0,1,3,2,2};
auto x = upper_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 1);
cout<<(*x);
```

This block gives output 2.

Why?

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake in the `upper_bound` function?

Comment: This `upper_bound` is not my code, it's STL @mkrieger1

Comment: Related: [why is using namespace std considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I didn't know that, because you didn't show it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], i.e. some code that we can actually copy&paste and compile.

Comment: The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the expression !(value < element) or !comp(value, element), i.e., all elements for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which the expression is false. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.

Comment: `x` is at the end so dereferencing it has undefined behaviour: https://godbolt.org/z/cMsjxoqvG

Comment: @mingzi xingshi The function expects a sorted sequence. Your sequences are not sorted. So the calls of the function have undefined behavior.

Comment: Assuming you mean `std::upper_bound`, your input vectors are not partitioned as described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound. You need to sort the vectors first.

Comment: You get an iterator to *last*, which means you access memory out of the vector.

Comment: Use [max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) instead.

Comment: @ThomasWeller -- you provided a clearly correct solution in a comment and another constructive comment, but you voted to close because the question isn't clear? How does that make sense?

Comment: @PeteBecker: as I commented before: I'd like to see a [mre]. As the question stands, it's a guess, probably a good guess, though.

Comment: I think this question contains all the information a C++ programmer needs to answer the issue. A MRE is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

`std::upper_bound` has a precondition. Quoting cppreference here, not the standard:

> The range `[first, last)` must be partitioned with respect to the expression `!(value < element)` or `!comp(value, element)`, i.e., all elements for which the expression is `true` must precede all elements for which the expression is `false`.

It is up to you, the caller, to make sure this precondition is satisfied, and your program has undefined behavior if you fail to do so.

Since you pass reverse iterators, the sequence for the algorithm is `2, 3, 1, 0` for the first example. (The second has exactly the same issue.) The expression `!(1 < element)` evaluates for this sequence to `false, false, true, true`, which means the `true` values don't precede the `false` values, i.e. the precondition is violated. Your program has undefined behavior, and the exact resulting values are unpredictable and irrelevant.